# US citizen go to Japan and Korea

Tags: visas

I have a plan to travel to Japan for 17 days, from LAX to Osaka, arriving at 18:30 at Kansai airport. From Kansai airport I buy another ticket to go to Korea at 19:30 on the same day and spend 3 days in Korea. From Korea I go back to Osaka and spend 14 days in Japan. Do I need to do something when I go like that? Do I need to pass through security or do I just change airlines and go?

Comment: From the sound of it, you bought a LAX-Osaka round trip, and then separately bought an Osaka-Korea round trip? Or did you book a LAX->Osaka->Korea one-way flight, with a separate Korea->Osaka flight and an Osaka->LAX flight? The difference is very important in this case, since you only have 1 hour between flights.

Comment: I bought ticket mutil lax-osaka , Narita- viet nam , viet nam -lax when I arrived osaka  18h15 I buy another one tickets round trip go korea 19h 45 , I spent 3 day at korea and comeback osaka  I spent 14 day in japan before next trip to viet nam, I don’t have anything carry , just only handbag or backbag

Comment: Ah, okay. So you have a LAX->Osaka one-way booking, and a *separate* Osaka->Korea booking, it sounds like? Plus some others, but the Osaka/Korea tickets are the relevant ones for this. And, you've already booked these tickets but haven't yet flown, right?

Comment: The ticket osaka to Korea not booked yet, jut looking and plan

Comment: Ah, good! Before you book the ticket, definitely double-check that you're giving yourself sufficient time between flights for the full transfer process (it will take longer than a normal transfer). It might be good to edit into your question the fact that you've got only carry-on bags, and that you haven't yet booked Osaka->Korea but have already booked the LAX-Osaka ticket (if that's the case).

Answer (score 8):

If I'm correct in interpreting this as **two separately-booked round trips** (LAX-Osaka round trip with a separate Osaka-Korea round trip), then this might be **difficult to do successfully** due to the (short) **1 hour time between flights**.

**Getting to your next flight**: You will generally need to pass through security when transferring. This takes a bit of time, but not too long. Additionally, for a separate booking, **you will need to check in separately for your Osaka -> Korea flight**. You might not have sufficient time to check in at the airport, with a 1-hour layover; it depends on the airline. You should definitely **contact the airline flying you to Korea and ask if this will work**.

**Transiting through Japan**: Since it sounds like you have separate bookings, sterile transit might not apply, meaning **you might have to go through Japanese immigration before transferring to your Korean flight** (even though you're not staying until later!). This will be somewhat tricky on a 1-hour layover. If you can't change the booking to allow for some more time between flights, then I would advise finding out whether there are any special procedures that would let you skip immigration during transit "on a separate booking" (i.e., specifically look into the "separate booking" phrase). I am not sure if such procedures are available in Japan or not.

**Getting your bags to your next flight**: If you have a separate booking, you will likely need to claim your baggage and then check it in with the next flight. Baggage claim has been one of the most time-consuming parts of the post-flight procedure, in my experience, and I do not expect this to be possible within 1 hour. If you do have a separate booking with only 1 hour between flights, I would advise flying with carry-on luggage only, and not bringing any checked luggage.

**Procedure when entering Japan and South Korea** (regardless of timing): both Japan and South Korea allow US citizens to stay as a tourist for up to 90 days visa-free (you did mean South Korea, yes?). Your total trip is much less than that, so this obviously applies. Therefore, no visa is required. However, from personal experience, **Japanese Immigration staff will ask where you're staying, and Korea will likely do the same**; if you've booked a hotel or have other accommodations, good! If not, it would be a good idea to arrange for accommodations before you arrive, at least for the first day or two. (I nearly made this mistake when I decided to "wing it" on my first time really being a tourist, but luckily I booked a hotel at the last minute)

Lastly, have fun with your trip! Hopefully you can arrange things to work. At the very least, call your airline, to see if they can assist.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to pass through security or do I just change airlines and go?

Security? Yes. Immigration? No. In KIX you'll pass through transfer security check (X-ray, metal detector, etc), and go onwards to your next flight.

On your way back from Korea, when you stay in Japan for two weeks, you'll have to pass immigration and customs, of course.

Comment: This likely won't be the case if the OP has bought separate tickets (especially if they have checked luggage, which will need to be claimed and checked in with the second airline). Allowing just an hour between flights on separate tickets is a really bad idea.